# How do I assign multiple strings to one variable?

Tags: python

So I have tried searching this but apparently nobody ever needed to do this simple thing before?

I want to a variable to have multiple strings. so basically it is:

```
command = input()
commands = "start" or "stop" or "help"

 while command.lower() == commands:
    dosomething()
 else
    dosomething()
```

This is basically the idea, but it only take the first string which is "start" but ignores the other 2. I understand that it reads it as ( commands = "start" ) so I tried making it
`commands = "start" or commands = "stop" or commands = "help"`
but it flat out says it is wrong. so what did I do instead?
Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Normally you'd put all the (accepted) values in a list and use the `in` operator to check if the input it's one of them. Also, you could also throw a `.strip()` in there to ease things a little.

Comment: I can assure you millions of people have already tried to this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Comment: You can only assign a *single* object to a variable. That object can be a *container*, though, like a `list`, `dict` or `tuple`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `list`, then check for inclusion with `if` (not `while` which is a loop)

```
command = input(">>")
commands = ["start", "stop", "help"]

if command.lower() in commands:
    print("start/stop/help")
else:
    print("other")
```